# too few arguments to function 'exit'. What is wrong in code?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    int a[10],i,q;
    printf("Enter elements of array\n");
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    printf("enter number to search: ");
    scanf("%d",&q);
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(q==a[i])
        {
            printf("Given number is at %dth place", i);
            getch();
            exit();
        }
}
    printf("Given number is not found");
    getch();
}
```

Here I'm facing error " [Warning] incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'exit' " and " [Error] too few arguments to function 'exit' "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`exit()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) takes one argument `status` to determint the exit code of the program, so you have to provide that (one integer).

Also you should add `#include <stdlib.h>` to use `exit()` function because the header includes required declaration of the function.